# How to include different assets folder(css/js) in different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I bought many layout themes from https://wrapbootstrap.com

For example, I have `lenord-single-page-theme` and `ace-admin-theme`

and wanna apply `lenord-single-page-theme` in `controller welcome` (Apply on those view pages generated by scaffold)

And apply `ace-admin-theme` on the all other controllers excepts `controller welcome`

But now, I only know how to append the `lenord-single-page-theme` to all pages in my project.

But not knowing how to apply some themes on some specific controller.

Because `those themes have dependency issues`,

I can not import all of them  in one controller.

I want the mapping policy is that all the new created controller will include the assets folder

`ace-admin-theme` by default,

and I can also apply some specific controller to include other assets folder for the special case.

For example, I only need the 'welcome controller' to include the `lenord-single-page-theme` folder

Thanks.

The following code only apply it on all the views of my project

```
javascripts/application.js
16://= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/js/.

stylesheets/application.css.scss
13: *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/css/.
```

Here's my assets folder structure

```
vendor
└── assets
    ├── ace-admin-theme
    │   ├── avatars
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── font
    │   ├── images
    │   ├── img
    │   └── js
    ├── javascripts
    ├── lenord-single-page-theme
    │   ├── css
    │   ├── fonts
    │   ├── img
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── js
    │   └── rs-assets
```

[image]

Comment: `Theme`? You mean `layout`?

Comment: probably a theme as in something purchased off themeforest or the like, a CSS/JS combo.

Comment: Yes, @sevenseacat is right~ that's what i mean

Comment: @sevenseacat Thanks! I will get used to it soon :)